# Vertices, cusps and osculations

Tags: geometry, curvature

Reading the [Vertex (curve)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_%28curve%29) Wikipedia page, the section about cusps and osculation says:

> Although a single generic curve will not have any higher-order vertices, they will generically occur within a one-parameter family of curves, at the curve in the family for which two ordinary vertices coalesce to form a higher vertex and then annihilate.

I'm a little confused about what this is implying. Can you perhaps reword it, provide an example, and/or pictures? Especially the last part of the explanation, about forming a higher vertex and then annihilation....
Thank you.